Pyright with multiple venv (monorepo)
Got an issue with pyright on a monorepo: it didn't recognize classes/functions imported from nearby projects/libraries (get a reportMissingImports).
For instance, with this repo structure:
.
├── library
|   └── src
|       └── __init__.py
├── project1
|   └── src
|       └── main.py
├── project2 ...
└── pyproject.toml

This line in main.py will raise the reportMissingImports error (even if the code is working):
from library import ModuleClass

As a manual workaround, this command works from root level:
poetry run pyright --pythonpath project1/.venv/bin/python project1/main.py

But as I have multiple projects, each with its own .venv folder, I can't set pythonpath globally.
I tried multiple options in pyproject.toml to configure pyright properly for the whole repository, but nothing worked so far.
What is the proper way to configure multiple venv like that with pyright ?
FYI, as a context, my final goal is to setup pyright for sublime text 3 with LSP-pyright and python >=3.11. But at least command line should work before that (-‿-")

I am assuming you are using this. Which says at the bottom of the readme: If you want to overwrite the virtual environment, the pyrightconfig.json file must be present at the root of your project. Have you attempted this and opened the project at the right level?

Hi ! Yep, pyrightconfig.json is at root level and I run it from there. But the issue is event in pyright command line, so...
I made some improvement by setting extraPaths. I'll update my question with my config file

Good catch!, it improved a lot when I reopen the project folder with sublime, and not by adding each subdir folders to the project. Still have an issue with pyright command line, about external libs (a dependency in project1 that is not present in other folders).

And btw, LSP-pyright don't seems to handle pyproject.toml config

Multiple things here :

Sublime text project needs to target the root dir. I used to open my project by adding each subdir, but in fact its a bad idea ;
LSP-pyright seems to also read pyproject.toml config at root level (not precised in its documentation) ;
my final pyrightconfig.json file is pretty simple:

{
    //"verboseOutput": true,
    "reportMissingImports": "none",
    "reportMissingModuleSource": "none",
    "executionEnvironments": [
        {
          "root": ".",
          "extraPaths": ["library/src", "project1/src", "project2/src"]
        }
    ]
}

extraPaths is resolved from root dir. It needs the src/ subdir declaration.
